# Tableau not reading csv file date when using python to print to csv file

Tags: python, date, csv, tableau-api

I am using Python to calculate some metrics then using Tableau 9.1 to visualize them.

I use

```
  df['Filedate'] = dt.date(2016, 3, 22) for today as an example
```

and use

```
  with open('filename.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
      df.to_csv(csvfile, sep = ',', header=False)
```

That prints the data to a csv. I then have Tableau set with my visualizations pulling from filename.csv.

Every time I refresh the new data in Tableau, my Filedate is showing as null. When I open filename.csv and save it and then refresh in Tableau the dates are showing as dates.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I opened the CSV file in Excel (my default program for opening CSV files) and after that the filedate would not load properly into Tableau. I tested this using random data that worked until I opened the file in Excel.

No Excel next time :)